# Facebook.net C# SDK and login into Asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Can I achive the following with the "Facebook.net C# SDK"?

•Allow users to register in my asp.net site using their facebook credentials.
•Retrieve facebook client information. Like (Name, surname, email address etc). So I can import this information into my application.
•Allow users to log into my site using facebook credentials.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All of the above is easily possible.

I think that this resource offers a good tutorial on how to integrate with Facebook's user infrastructure:

http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-retrieve-user-data-from-facebook-connect-in-aspnet/

There is also this code example / framework which takes you though much of the process:

http://fbconnectauth.codeplex.com/

And this walkthrough which is a little more up-to-date:

http://area72.ro/general-it/how-to-login-via-facebook-in-asp-net.html

Comment: isnt there a difference  between "Facebook Connect" and the "Facebook.net C# SDK"?

Comment: There are examples explicitly for the SDK here: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Step 19 of this tutorial shows you how to get user-information using the FaceBookClient object: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website&referringTitle=Getting%20Started

Comment: Also you may want to look at the following which gives a nice overview of using the SDK with MVC: http://onishimura.com/2010/08/11/facebook-c-and-asp-net-mvc-code-samples-for-friends-list-activities-list-and-wall-posts/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, review the [Facebook Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/) for more details.